# vSphere APIs and automating VM management

Tags: c, api, vmware

We are exploring the possibility of interfacing our software with different VMware virtualization products, most notably with vSphere 5 (ESXi) and vCloud Director. We wish to automate creation (clone), deletion, start, stop, and installation of a particular software on VMs both outside and inside the cloud.

These questions concern vSphere (ESXi), vCloud director is for later. Having trawled the VMware documentation we chose to make a Proof of Concept (POC) for vSphere using the vCLI interface on Linux.This is a bit slow and we pass ip, user and password in clear text to perform these tasks.

- Is there a better way of doing this (more efficient and/or secure)?
- Would you recommend other APIs?
- Any C libraries that would be able to perform these tasks?
- What is the most commonly used API for automating management of VMs?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about some API's on linux (Windows would be probably better choice), but I have these comments:

- we are developing quite similar system and all our tasks we do through [vSphere Web Services SDK](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/) (I think only C# and Java are officially supported by VMware, but I have heard about many community SDKs in PHP, Perl etc.)
- [PowerCLI](http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/server/vsphere/automationtools/powercli) is second recommended API which is pretty easy to use
- however if you really wants to go with Linux, the VSphere uses SOAP to communicate, you just must know the format of the messages etc. here I would recommend [Onyx project](http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/server/vsphere/automationtools/onyx), which works as some kind of proxy between VSphere client and VCenter and you just do stuff in VSphere client and it shows you exact SOAP messages it sent to the server

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late but I've been all over alternative VSphere APIs recently. I'm looking at deploying from inside a Continuous Integration service like Jenkins.

I'm currently trying out 
[rbvmomi](https://github.com/rlane/rbvmomi) which is a 'Ruby interface to the VSphere API'. This might be more useful to you in the Linux world. The rbvmomi author has also penned  [Ruby VSphere Console (RVC)](http://labs.vmware.com/flings/rvc) which is worth checking out. I don't know whether this supports VCloud Director though.

Good luck!

Comment: Just a quick update. I'm using Fog now [link](http://fog.io). Seems to be quite comprehensive.